# EasyPhp DevServer 16.1 and Wordpress "http Transports" problems

Tags: php, wordpress, easyphp

I use DevServer 16.1 in Windows 10 pro 64bit OS.
I use it to work in localhost my WordPress sites.
Now I have some problems to update plugins and WordPress system.
When I try to update the system return me this message:

> "There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request."

I have searched in google to find a solution but nothing I don't found any worked solutions.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in SSL.
Go to your php.ini and uncomment this line: ";extension=php_openssl.dll".

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, but i didnt find the uncommented line, i just added the suggested code in the last line.

By the way, i found the php.ini file here C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x161209105824